# Using FolderBrowserDialog folder as path

Tags: c#

Hi I'm trying to make the user able to open a folder using FolderBrowserDialog and then set that folder as a path. I'm not really sure how, here is how I did so far:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeGUI();
    }
    public void InitializeGUI()
    {

         int fileCount = Directory.GetFiles(?????, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
        textBox1.Text = fileCount.ToString();
    }
    //When the user clicks select file
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath);
    }
}
```

What should be put as a file path? I want the file path to be the selected folder.

Comment: If the result == DialogResult.OK then fbd.SelectedPath will be the selected folder. I don't know what it is if the dialog is canceled.  I do know that you should not attempt to use it if the dialog is canceled.

Comment: Are you trying to use the selected path in your `InitializeGUI` method? If that's the case, then the dialog must be displayed before the method runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following for displaying the standad FolderBrowserDialog

```
var folderBrowserDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();

folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath = "c:\temp";
folderBrowserDialog.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
folderBrowserDialog.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;
folderBrowserDialog.Description = "Select the folder to generate the new documents within";

var dialogResult = folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog();
```

Selected directory can then be retrieved with

```
var selectedDirectory = folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath;
```